the sum variable is not aggregated
I am trying to set up a script to calculate the monthly loan payment, but with the condition that if the loan term is less than 4 months, interest is not charged. But in line 25 I get the error monthcredit undefined, how can I fix this? The result is displayed on the links #msum and #ovsum. Tilda website builder.
Bad code -
<!-- Как сделать калькулятор расчета аннуитетных платежей по кредиту в ZeroBlock в Tilda mo-ti.ru --><script src="https://static.tildacdn.com/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" charset="utf-8" onerror="this.loaderr='y';"></script>
<style>
    a[href="#msum"] , a[href="#ovsum"] {pointer-events:none;}
</style>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    //Значение процента    
    var percent = 10;
    $(".tn-atom__form").on('input', ".t-range", function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
             let summa = $('input[name="summa"]').next('.t-range__value-txt').html();
             let srok = $('input[name="srok"]').next('.t-range__value-txt').html();
             let monthPercent = percent/100/12;
             //Возведение в степень
             let degree = Math.pow( 1+monthPercent , -srok);
             if (srok <= 4) {
                 let monthCredit = summa/srok;
             let overCredit =0
             } else {
             let monthCredit = summa*(monthPercent/(1-degree));
             let overCredit = monthCredit*srok-summa
                 
             }
             //Выводим итоги в текст
             monthCredit = monthCredit.toFixed();
                 overCredit = overCredit.toFixed();
                 monthCredit = monthCredit.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
                 overCredit = overCredit.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');     
             $('a[href="#msum"]').html(monthCredit+' руб.');
             $('a[href="#ovsum"]').html(overCredit+' руб.');
        }, 100);
    });
});
</script>

I have the same working script, but it does not provide for the condition about 4 months (attached below) -
Working code -
 <!-- Как сделать калькулятор расчета аннуитетных платежей по кредиту в ZeroBlock в Tilda mo-ti.ru --><script src="https://static.tildacdn.com/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" charset="utf-8" onerror="this.loaderr='y';"></script>
<style>
    a[href="#msum"] , a[href="#ovsum"] {pointer-events:none;}
</style>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    //Значение процента    
    var percent = 10;
    $(".tn-atom__form").on('input', ".t-range", function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
             let summa = $('input[name="summa"]').next('.t-range__value-txt').html();
             let srok = $('input[name="srok"]').next('.t-range__value-txt').html();
             let monthPercent = percent/100/12;
             //Возведение в степень
             let degree = Math.pow( 1+monthPercent , -srok);
             let monthCredit = summa*(monthPercent/(1-degree));
             let overCredit = monthCredit*srok-summa
             //Выводим итоги в текст
             monthCredit = monthCredit.toFixed();
             overCredit = overCredit.toFixed();
             monthCredit = monthCredit.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
             overCredit = overCredit.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');   
             $('a[href="#msum"]').html(monthCredit+' руб.');
             $('a[href="#ovsum"]').html(overCredit+' руб.');
             
       }, 100);
    });
});
</script>.


let variables are block scoped, therefore, declaring them in if or else they won't be visible outside the if or else block

The monthCredit identifier is only declared in either of the if (srok <= 4) logic branches' scopes, so it's not declared in the next higher scope where the rest of the function is trying to use/reference it.
Move the monthCredit declaration out of the if-branches. Same for overCredit.
Example:
$(document).ready(function() {
  var percent = 10;
  $(".tn-atom__form").on('input', ".t-range", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      let summa = $('input[name="summa"]').next('.t-range__value-txt').html();
      let srok = $('input[name="srok"]').next('.t-range__value-txt').html();
      let monthPercent = percent / 100 / 12;
      let degree = Math.pow(1 + monthPercent, -srok);

      // Declared in this scope
      let monthCredit = 0;
      let overCredit = 0;

      if (srok <= 4) {
        monthCredit = summa / srok;
        overCredit = 0;
      } else {
        monthCredit = summa * (monthPercent / (1 - degree));
        overCredit = monthCredit * srok - summa;
      }

      monthCredit = monthCredit.toFixed();
      overCredit = overCredit.toFixed();
      monthCredit = monthCredit.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
      overCredit = overCredit.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');

      $('a[href="#msum"]').html(monthCredit + ' руб.');
      $('a[href="#ovsum"]').html(overCredit + ' руб.');
    }, 100);
  });
});
</script>

